# ResEdit Decompilers

Tags: software-development, mac-os-classic, disassembly

What de-compilers were available for ResEdit? A friend used a de-compiler to break the copy protection on [F/A-18 Hornet](https://www.mobygames.com/game/fa-18-hornet) and I remember having one to examine how programs worked. To clarify by de-compiler, I mean for 68k/PPC CODE disassembly not just resources in general.

Comment: What is a ‘decompiler for ResEdit’? A decompiler capable of analysing exactly that one program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be thinking of [Resorcerer](http://www.mathemaesthetics.com/ResorcererIndex.html) (apparently still available for purchase), which was like a beefed up version of ResEdit and included CODE disassembly functionality.

[Macintosh Garden](https://macintoshgarden.org/apps/resorcerer-125) has some screenshots of the older version.

Apple also had a [CODE editor for ResEdit](https://macintoshgarden.org/apps/code-editor-resedit-21) which was sometimes distributed as "Super ResEdit"

Comment: I own a copy of Resorcerer, though it's PPC only so I have to use it in emulation. It does have a CODE disassembly function.

Comment: Resourcer had excellent AppleScript integration. At one job I produced a script that looked for strings in a sample file, matched them against a column in Excel (which also had pretty good AS support), replaced them with the string in the next column, presto, instant localization.

Answer (score 5):

The MPW toolchain for Classic Mac OS which was available for free at ftp.apple.com comes with the DeRez tool that can decompile resource forks: http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/tools/mpw-tools/commandref/derez.html

The internet archive has a backup of the ftp site for historical purposes, but I can't confirm the url as archive.org is itself down for maintainance right now.

Comment: MPW also has a `DumpCode` command which will disassemble CODE resources.