# Open an RSRC "sound file" from a Mac OS 6/9 application

Tags: file-format, sound, mac-os-classic

I have been looking in the files of this 90s Mac game [MacSki](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/4655-macski), made by D. Cook. Using [Infinite Mac emulator](https://infinitemac.org/), I've been able to open it and make it work quite well (some keyboard issue, well).

We obtain those files :

[image]

Among the files, one can find a "MacSki Sounds" file, which seems to contain all… sounds from the game. Was there some specific format for these files at the time or is it a custom format? And subsequently, is there a way to convert it? I can open the file and read this at its beginning (choosing Mac Roman encoding):

```
v1.5?MacSki Sounds v1.5, Copyright © 1990-1994 by Storm Impact, Inc.
This support document contains all of the sounds for the MacSki application. 
Place this in the exact same folder as the MacSki application.
```

The file is available here: [file.io/sgrt6iECvLo1](https://file.io/sgrt6iECvLo1) but can easily be downloaded with Infinite Mac the way I explained.

---

---

**Edit1:**

Result when opened with ResEdit. It is correctly understood as a sound file:
[image]

The hex datas look like this:

[image]

( https://pastebin.com/2Rb13H1u )

Comment: I remember that game! If the sounds are in a resource file, I would just use ResEdit (or Resourcerer) to extract them.

Comment: Thanks @GlenYates , ResEdit seems to understand it is a sound indeed. I've made an edit to my answer. Any hint on how to decipher it? I'm totally unfamiliar with MacOS and didn't find any hint in the documentation…

PS : a game from my childhood too haha

Comment: However that's easy with Resorcerer https://macintoshgarden.org/apps/resorcerer-125

Thanks, I'll add an answer later to close the topic.

Comment: Does anyone remember the "quack" app from the MAC SE/30 around 1990?

Comment: I don't, what was it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the answer was to use Resorcerer on the InfiniteMac emulator as explained by Glen Yates in a comment, and using this answer from [Kelvin Sherlock](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/20111/27041) to install it we get :

[image]

You can listen to the sound by opening each track and clicking on "Sound Me Out!":

[image]

To extract the sound, I then simply used audacity.

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah. Classic MacOS apps were the *king* of moddability and easy resource extraction because Apple provided a standard metaformat (the resource fork) for application resources to be bundled into packfiles or into the application binary itself, a standard tool for modifying packfiles (ResEdit), standard library functions for loading assets from resource forks with document→prefs→binary→system fallback chaining, and "store your assets in your resource fork" was the official training for new mac programmers. It's really a shame that we've regressed from that.

Comment: Interesting @ssokolow , thx! I was a child in the 90s, so I was totally unaware of all this, especially since I had no development tools on the macs I was allowed to touch at the time. I only discovered dev later on windows or linux and never went back to mac! Just wanted to get some sounds from old mac games haha